# Can't run Neo4j on Antergos (integer expression expected)

Tags: linux, neo4j, archlinux

Every time I try to run the latest version of Neo4j (2.3.2 Community) I keep getting an error that just keeps looping.

```
[telmo@Telmo-LT neo4j-community-2.3.2]$ bin/neo4j start
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
bin/neo4j: line 150: [: : integer expression expected
bin/neo4j: line 153: lsof: command not found
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [1283]... waiting for server to be ready.bin/neo4j: line 150: [: : integer expression expected
bin/neo4j: line 153: lsof: command not found
.bin/neo4j: line 150: [: : integer expression expected
bin/neo4j: line 153: lsof: command not found
.bin/neo4j: line 150: [: : integer expression expected
bin/neo4j: line 153: lsof: command not found
.bin/neo4j: line 150: [: : integer expression expected
bin/neo4j: line 153: lsof: command not found
```

This is a stable release and I couldn't find anyone with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you run the 'lsof' command in your shell? Looks like it is missing on your machine. It's used to define the PID of the neo4j process and failing in your case. Just have a look into the /bin/neo4j file and see what fails. I had some issues with the lsof version number which caused the IF in line 150 to fail. I ended up using a dirty hack to get it running by just hard coding the version number.

Comment: Awesome, man! Just did a "sudo pacman -S lsof" and I was able to run the server. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

line 153: lsof: command not found, you can try install losf,I use centos system, and use this command `yum install lsof -y`,then try bin/neo4j start